# How do I call a function dynamically through my loop?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I don't really know how to phrase my question because im quite new to Ionic and hybrid app development in gerneral but I'll try my best. Im working on an app and want to open a `ion-select` field by clicking onto another button.

It somewhat works but it doesn't delete the right entry if the clicked entry isn't the first one.

My HTML-Code looks like this:

**account.page.html**

```html
<div class="account-drop-wrapper" *ngFor="let item of myDrops">
  <div class="account-item">
    <div class="account-content" [routerLink]="['/drop', item.id]">
      <div class="text-content">
        {{ item.description }}
      </div>
      <div class="drop-score">
        <ion-progress-bar color="primary" value="0.5"></ion-progress-bar>
        <p>{{ item.score }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <ion-item class="more-button">
        <ion-icon name="more" class="edit-icon" (click)="openSelect()"></ion-icon>
        <ion-select class="select-field" interface="action-sheet" (ionChange)="showMore(item, $event)" #showSelect>
          <ion-select-option value="delete">Löschen</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="edit">Bearbeiten</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my TypeScript so far:

**account.page.ts**

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { DropService } from '../../services/drop.service';
    import { Events, IonSelect, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-account',
      templateUrl: './account.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./account.page.scss'],
    })
    export class AccountPage implements OnInit {

      allDrops: Drop[];
      myDrops: Drop[];

      @ViewChild('showSelect') selectRef: IonSelect;

      openSelect() {
        this.selectRef.open();
      }

      constructor(private dropService: DropService, 
         public navCtrl: NavController, 
         public events: Events, 
         public alertController: AlertController) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.dropService.getDrops().subscribe(res => {
              this.allDrops = res;
          });

        this.dropService.getMyDrops().subscribe(res => {
          this.myDrops = res;
        });
      }

      showMore(item, event) {
        if (event.detail.value === 'delete') {
          this.confirmDelete(item);
        }
      }

      async confirmDelete(item) {
        const alert = await this.alertController.create({
          header: 'Confirm',
          message: 'delete?',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'cancel',
              role: 'cancel',
              cssClass: 'secondary'
            }, {
              text: 'delete',
              handler: () => {
                this.dropService.removeDrop(item.id);
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        await alert.present();
      }
    }
```

I guess I need to make each `ion-select` unique, something like this:

```html
    <ion-select (ionChange)="showMore(item, $event)" #showSelect{{item.id}}>
```

But unfortunatly I don't know the right syntax to achieve this.. Can anybody help me out or correct me if I'm wrong about my guess?

Comment: Can we see how `item` is defined in your template?

Comment: Also are there multiple `ion-select`?

Comment: I edited the HTML part. Yes there are, sorry forgot to add the loop to the html-part.

Comment: @Brecherchef I've added an answer before you edited the HTML code, but the main idea is exactly the same. Instead of `allItems` you'd use the `myDrops` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have several `ion-select` components in your page, and you need to get a reference of a certain `ion-select` to open it from your code.

I'm assuming the `ion-select` components are inside of an `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of allItems" class="some-class">

  <!-- Some other content... -->

  <!-- Send the item to the openSelect() method -->
  <ion-icon name="more" class="edit-icon" (click)="openSelect(item)"></ion-icon>

  <ion-select (ionChange)="showMore(item, $event)" #showSelect>
    <!-- options... -->
  </ion-select>

</div>
```

If that's correct, then you can use [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) in your component to get all the instances of the `ionSelect` component, and then find the right one based on its index like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { DropService } from '../../services/drop.service';
import { Events, IonSelect, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.page.scss'],
})
export class AccountPage implements OnInit {

  // Now it's a QueryList of IonSelect instances
  @ViewChildren('showSelect') selectRefs: QueryList<IonSelect>;

  // This is the list of all the items that you use in the ngFor
  public allItems: Array<any>;

  openSelect(item: any) {

    // First find the index of the item in the allItems array
    const targetIndex = allItems.findIndex(someItem => someItem.id === item.id);

    if(targetIndex > -1) {

      // then get the IonSelect from the QueryList using the same index
      const targetIonSelect = this.selectRefs.toArray()[targetIndex];

      if(targetIonSelect) {

        // Now you can open that IonSelect instance
        targetIonSelect.open();

      }

    }

  }

  // ...

}
```

Comment: I've tried this one. I'll edit the code in my question so you can see my adjustments. So far it's not working for me, my console throws this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: @Brecherchef Are you sending the item in the `openSelect()` method in your HTML code: `<ion-icon name="more" class="edit-icon" (click)="openSelect(item)"></ion-icon>` ?

Comment: Ou whups. Ye my bad. Thank you very much, this one worked for me!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)